# Android admob, what to do onAdFailedToLoad code == ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL

Tags: android, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

The error is pretty self explanatory, but the desired behavior is kind of unkwon...

What should we do when admob returns there isn't ad to fill a banner (or a video reward)?

- should we retry instantly?
- should we wait a few moments (how long) and retry?
- should we just let it empty?

I'm actually retrying immediatly and i noticed that it lead to a very low match rate!! and after match rate declined ecpm also declined i guess they are somehow connected